# Solr filtering multiple children in nested documents

Tags: solr

I couldn't find out how to filter out only the relevant children in nested documents and returning them along with the parents, something like:

*Return all parents which have child documents with attribute1=value1 and attribute1=value2 and return only those children with the parent*.

The structure of *one* document looks like this:

```
{
 category: parent,
 attr1: a,
 attr2: b,
   _childDocuments_ : [
   {
        category:child,
        childAttr1: x,
        // many more
   },
   {
        category:child,
        childAttr1: y,
        // many more
   }, 
   {
   // more children but should not be returned
   }]
}
```

Using the child transformer all the children are returned. Using multiple childFilters inside the `[child]` transformer has no effect (first one is taken second, one is ignored).

An example query would be

```
query='+attr1:(*)+{!parent which=category:parent}childAttr1:x 
       +{!parent which=category:parent}childAttr1:y', 
       'fl':'*,[child parentFilter=category:parent childFilter=childAttr1:x11]'
```

I am using the JSON API for querying, grouping the result by a parent attribute and filtering on some parent attributes, but that shouldn't matter (imho).

Thanks a lot for your time and I hope the question is well written.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for would be along the lines of:

```
&q={!parent which=category:parent}(+field:value1 AND field:value2)

&fl=*,[child childFilter="field:value1 AND field:value2" parentFilter=category:parent]
```